# How to resume a movie that's being played with presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated

Tags: objective-c, ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm uisng this code to display a movie:

```
 MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
 initWithContentURL:movieURL];
 mp.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeUnknown;
 [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp]; [mp.moviePlayer play];
```

The code is working fine. However when the application goes to the background while playing a movie, when the app comes back in the foreground the movieplayer is not displayed. (I see the view of the controller that called `presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp`

Is it possible when entering the foregound to resume the movie that was playing before the app went to the background?

Comment: Still I am not getting solution. How you resolve your Problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the UIBackgroundmode to audio and also there has been problem with playing the video after app enters foreground .Refer this [Tutorial on MPMoviePlayerViewController](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/audio-video/play-video-with-mpmovieplayercontroller-in-ios-3-0-and-3-24-0)  Also you can try using MPMoviePlayerViewController which has options for implementing various notifications .

Answer (score 0):

you can implement notification techniques to handle it. Add a notification in the class where movie player is playing and associate with it a selector. When app goes to background then in the delegate method

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application

{

// Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 

 // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.


    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = 0;

    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    }];

}
```

write this code.Actually when app goes background it pauses the MPMoviePlayerController so when it is coming to foreground you post the notification which call the method in class where movie controller is implemented and play it again in this method.

```
-(void)playIntroAnimationAgain

{

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:NOTIFICATION_PlayAgain_Player object:nil];

        [self.moviePlayerController play];

       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playIntroAnimationAgain)name:NOTIFICATION_PlayAgain_Player object:nil];
}
```

It solved my problem.