# MPMoviePlayerController getting paused when app enters in background

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to resume a movie that’s being played with presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566666/how-to-resume-a-movie-thats-being-played-with-presentmovieplayerviewcontrollera)

I am playing an video when my app starts but at the mean time when i press home button it pauses the video or hang the video how to resume it when my app enters in foreground it is possible to resume MPMoviePlayerController.Any suggestion would be beneficial for me

Thanks

Comment: Hi @ashutosh. I am having the same problem. And I am unable to resolve. Can u plz tell me if you got any solution.

Comment: Yeah use notification when app enters in background and comes to foreground to pause and play the MoviePlayercontroller

Comment: Yah thq 4 responding. But I need to play the video in background. How can I go further?

Comment: what is the need to play video in background when you can't see it. You can play audio instead. Isn't it?