# resume MPMoviePlayerViewController after ending phone call

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am developing an iphone app in which I am playing streaming audio by using MPMoviePlayerViewController. Using following code, it works fine.

```
moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
[moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 83, 1024, 400)];
   moviePlayerController.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlModeVolumeOnly;
[moviePlayerController.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    moviePlayerController.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
   [moviePlayerController.moviePlayer play];
```

But when there is call during the playing player, it stops. I want to resume the player streaming song after recieving call. How can I do this?

Plaese any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Register a notification for it using **NSNotificationCenter**. So, when app comes to foreground, you can resume the playback.
It's the correct way to handle such events for any ios app.

For more information refer to [NSNotificationCenter Class Reference on apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

You can also [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566666/how-to-resume-a-movie-thats-being-played-with-presentmovieplayerviewcontrollera) to know the exact steps to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the method given implemented in your application delegate class

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

// Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you are invoking the player after got interrupted?

Answer (score -1):

Try these methods based on your situation...

```
-(void)audioPlayerBeginInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)audioPlayer;
{
    [self.audioPlayer pause];
}

-(void)audioPlayerEndInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)audioPlayer;
{
    [self.audioPlayer play];
}
```

and http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html for further help..